# Invite a B2B user (Azure AD guest account) with Microsoft Graph without redirection URL

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I can create an invitation for a B2B user by a POST to

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations
```

and with body

```
{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "yyy@test.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://myapp.com"
}
```

This redirects the user to "https://myapp.com" after they have redeemed their invitation.

**Is is possible to invite someone without redirecting them after redemption?**
If it's not absolutely necessary, I would like to avoid the hassle of hosting a confirmation webpage just for that purpose. However, the API does not accept a null or empty or relative URL for "inviteRedirectUrl".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not. The RedirectURL field is mandatory. You can, however, redirect to all kinds of URL's. So you *could* redirect to a generic page for your company, or google.com, or ...

> inviteRedirectUrl (String) The URL user should be redirected to once the invitation is redeemed. **Required**.

More information: [microsoft-graph-docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/invitation_post.md](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/api/invitation_post.md)

And another one: [HowTo: invite AAD user with Microsoft Graph](https://www.rickvandenbosch.net/blog/invite-aad-user-microsoft-graph/)

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much. Any idea why that is the case? Seems like a strange design decision to make it mandatory.

Comment: It's part of the OAuth 2.0 flow: https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/ Note that there's "out of band" "Uris", such as the powershell return uri, which looks something like this: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob which can allow you to use this flow without a "proper" return url. Edit: If you just want to save the "hassle" of the hosting itself, I strongly recommend you host that solo endpoint for this purpose.

Comment: @Svend: Sorry, I don't quite get your last sentence. Which solo endpoint and how would that help me avoid hosting a confirmation page myself?

Comment: Solo endpoint means that it's a single file endpoint. If you're a native app, there's no return uri for instance, which lets you avoid a file.